# Java – MySQL connection getter

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, getter

I need to send my connection to CarDAO class. I created getMyConn getter for that but it types me "myConn cannot be resolved to a variable". How could I create getter for that?

```
public class ConnectionDB {
    public ConnectionDB() {

        String dbHost="localhost";
        String dbDatabase="cars";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost
                + "/" + dbDatabase
                + "?user=" + dbUser
                + "&password=" + dbPassword;
        try{
        // 1. Get a connection do database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        // 2. Create a statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        // 3. Execute SQL query
        String sql = "";
        //int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        //System.out.println("Rows affected " + rowsAffected);
        // 4. Process the result set
        }
        catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Connection getMyConn(){
        return myConn;
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put **myConn** outside the constructor making it an attribute of the object.

```
 Connection myConn;
```

Then, in the constructor,

```
try{
    // 1. Get a connection do database
    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    // 2. Create a statement
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    // 3. Execute SQL query
    String sql = "";
    //int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    //System.out.println("Rows affected " + rowsAffected);
    // 4. Process the result set
}
```

Also, initializing the connection in the constructor is not recommended. You can use a singleton class to get the connection when required.